# Issues with EAX register when dividing by 10

Tags: assembly, masm, cpu-registers

I'm doing a simple program where I get user input for a numerical base and base number and then process it to output base-2, base-8, base-10, and base-16.  For instance, I'll input a numerical base of 5 and a number of 1234.  The question I have involves the eax register when processing the base-10 for output.  All other bases (base-2, 8, and 16) are working properly.  To give an example of the specific problem, I'm call DumpRegs to output the registers each pass through.

So with the example given above, base-5 and a number of 1234 the EAX register reads

```
EAX=000000C2
EAX=00000013
EAX=00006668        // This is obviously wrong because if 13h/Ah the answer 
                    // would be 9, and the EAX register would equal 00000001
```

The code I have for this is simple:

```
xor ebx, ebx
mov ebx, 10
mov esi, 0
Output:     
    div ebx
    mov finalVal[esi], dl
    inc esi
    cmp al, 0
    je EndOut
    jmp Output
```

After this section, I convert the value to an ASCII value and WriteChar, but this is the section where the issue resides.  Again, the conversion to base-2, base-8, and base-16 are perfect.  It's always with base-10 that this comes up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DIV EBX` does not just divide EAX by EBX, but the 64-bit number in EDX:EAX. Your code should set EDX to zero after taking the reminder from DL.

Furthermore, either your register dumper needs fixing, as it does not output the whole contents of EAX (it should be 40000013h / Ah, which is 66666668h, or you are using a 16-bit divide instruction (`DIV BX`) instead of a 32-bit divide instruction, which will not touch the upper half of EAX.